# Z3 statistics different over same problem, Bool. SAT Solver

Tags: python, z3

I am using the boolean SAT functionality in Z3 in python.

I noticed that multiple runs over the same problem yields different statistics. For example

```py
from z3 import *

solver = Solver()

problem = """p cnf 12 58
1 -2 3 0
2 -1 4 0
5 -2 6 0
1 -7 -8 0
5 -9 1 0
-10 3 11 0
-6 3 9 0
9 1 -6 0
-8 -5 -1 0
-5 7 11 0
-10 -4 7 0
4 -2 -12 0
-6 -11 -3 0
10 2 11 0
8 -11 7 0
-3 -7 -4 0
-3 7 12 0
3 12 -10 0
-10 -5 12 0
-11 5 -10 0
-8 -11 -4 0
11 -12 -9 0
-7 -1 -12 0
4 3 -10 0
-3 -9 2 0
-2 12 -1 0
2 6 4 0
8 -5 -9 0
11 1 -8 0
1 7 -11 0
12 2 -5 0
8 -9 -2 0
-11 10 -9 0
-9 12 10 0
5 -6 -2 0
12 -10 -4 0
5 6 -1 0
-7 12 -9 0
11 -5 -9 0
1 5 -9 0
5 -11 -1 0
-3 -6 -12 0
-9 10 -11 0
-10 1 -4 0
-9 8 -10 0
-3 4 1 0
-1 5 -11 0
12 5 11 0
-12 6 -7 0
-2 -7 6 0
3 -8 1 0
-5 -8 -9 0
-10 -7 12 0
-6 -3 -7 0
9 7 -3 0
-5 -1 -6 0
-5 8 9 0
-4 2 -7 0"""

## first run of problem 
solver.from_string(problem)
solver.check()
s1 = solver.statistics()

print(s1)

# reset solver
solver.reset()

solver.from_string(problem)
solver.check()
s2 = solver.statistics()

print(s2)
```

which prints the following:

```
(:max-memory            2.66
 :memory                2.54
 :mk-bool-var           1
 :num-allocs            31859
 :rlimit-count          1095
 :sat-backjumps         5
 :sat-conflicts         6
 :sat-decisions         6
 :sat-del-clause        14
 :sat-elim-clauses      7
 :sat-elim-literals     7
 :sat-minimized-lits    4
 :sat-mk-clause-2ary    10
 :sat-mk-clause-3ary    55
 :sat-mk-var            14
 :sat-propagations-2ary 5
 :sat-propagations-3ary 33
 :sat-units             1
 :time                  0.01)



(:max-memory            2.67
 :memory                2.54
 :mk-bool-var           1
 :num-allocs            62663
 :rlimit-count          2236
 :sat-backjumps         11
 :sat-conflicts         12
 :sat-decisions         12
 :sat-del-clause        14
 :sat-elim-clauses      4
 :sat-elim-literals     10
 :sat-minimized-lits    3
 :sat-mk-clause-2ary    13
 :sat-mk-clause-3ary    60
 :sat-mk-var            14
 :sat-propagations-2ary 9
 :sat-propagations-3ary 62
 :sat-units             4
 :time                  0.01)
```

Note the significant difference in `conflicts` (`6` in the first case versus `12` in the second case). Is there a reason for this involving some non-determinacy in the conflict resolution? Is the `reset` being used correctly here?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the random seed used in each call to `check()`. If you want (more) repeatable results, try the following:

```py
set_option('sat.random_seed', 1)
```

You can use any number as the seed, obviously. Do this at the beginning, and after every call to `solver.reset()`, and you should see the same statistics in each case. (Except for things like time/allocations etc., which I believe can be influenced by other settings that might differ from call to call.)

Note that there are other "random" settings inside z3 which might effect the statistics as well. To find out the whole set, try:

```
z3 -pd
```

and search for `random_seed` in the output. It is, unfortunately, almost impossible to say how these settings would impact different parts of the solver, without actually studying the source-code itself in depth.

Comment: right, thank you! After looking a bit closer at the implementation and the technical details (I'm still a bit of a novice in this area), this makes sense, though I'm still struck by such large differences.

Comment: When you have such a small problem, even small differences can swing the statistics widely. If you use much larger problems, the effect of random-seed should diminish to a large extent; though of course all of this is anecdotal.